# Adobe Flex plugin in eclipse helios / indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-flex, plugins

```
Windows 7 64 bit
Both JDK installed for 64 and 32 bit 
Eclipse Helios 32 bit 
Flex builder 4.5 32 bit 

I have installed Flex Builder and run exe from utility folder to add eclipse plugin .
I have added memory setting sin eclipse.ini
but eclipse crashes when i swicth to flex perspective .
log file 



#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d8832ca, pid=5688, tid=5152
#
# JRE version: 6.0_27-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.2-b06 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x932ca]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x02729000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=5152, stack(0x00090000,0x00190000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x02729000, ECX=0x00000006, EDX=0x6d883270
ESP=0x0018f260, EBP=0x0018f27c, ESI=0x2b02e9c8, EDI=0x02729000
EIP=0x6d8832ca, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0018f260)
0x0018f260:   02729000 2b02e9c8 2b02e9c8 02729000
0x0018f270:   00000000 02729618 027267c0 0018f294
0x0018f280:   3c5a4060 02729128 00000000 00000000
0x0018f290:   02729128 0018f2c8 3c5a3e17 00000000
0x0018f2a0:   00000000 00000006 063e0738 063dffd8
0x0018f2b0:   2b02e9c8 2b02e9c8 02729a4c 0018f320
0x0018f2c0:   06c20988 00729000 0018f320 02739fc7
0x0018f2d0:   02729128 0018f328 0018f354 0018f350 

Instructions: (pc=0x6d8832ca)
0x6d8832aa:   ff 8b 43 04 83 c4 08 85 c0 89 5d f0 c7 45 f4 00
0x6d8832ba:   00 00 00 74 08 8d 4d f0 e8 09 e2 09 00 8b 45 0c
0x6d8832ca:   8b 38 57 e8 ae a0 f8 ff 8d 70 01 56 e8 15 d1 06
0x6d8832da:   00 83 c4 08 85 c0 89 45 08 75 19 68 0c 74 a1 6d 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x02729000 is a thread
ECX=0x00000006 is an unknown value
EDX=0x6d883270 is an unknown value
ESP=0x0018f260 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x02729000
EBP=0x0018f27c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x02729000
ESI=0x2b02e9c8 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
EDI=0x02729000 is a thread


Stack: [0x00090000,0x00190000],  sp=0x0018f260,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x932ca]
C  [Headlights.dll+0x4060]  Java_com_adobe_flexide_nativelibs_Headlights_UTAddToGroup+0x70
C  [Headlights.dll+0x3e17]  Java_com_adobe_flexide_nativelibs_Headlights_AdobePIPInitialize+0x47
j  com.adobe.flexide.nativelibs.Headlights.AdobePIPInitialize(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;IJLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V+0
j  com.adobe.flexbuilder.ui.UIPlugin$2.run()V+117
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run()V+11
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+29
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+5
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+91
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Lorg/eclipse/jface/window/Window$IExceptionHandler;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;)V+9
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI()I+555
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/Workbench;)I+1
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run()V+55
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+18
j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+99
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+149
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xfac3b]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18c391]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfacbd]
V  [jvm.dll+0x104ec3]
V  [jvm.dll+0x105806]
V  [jvm.dll+0xb702e]
C  [java.dll+0x71e0]  Java_sun_reflect_NativeMethodAccessorImpl_invoke0+0x15
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xfac3b]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18c391]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfacbd]
V  [jvm.dll+0x95981]
V  [jvm.dll+0x976f9]
C  [eclipse_1312.dll+0x5fbb]  Java_org_eclipse_equinox_launcher_JNIBridge__1takedown_1splash+0x515
C  [eclipse_1312.dll+0x51ae]  runW+0x418f
C  [eclipse_1312.dll+0x15b0]  runW+0x591
C  [eclipse.exe+0x1414]
C  [eclipse.exe+0x1010]
C  [eclipse.exe+0x3029]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x133ca]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39ed2]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39ea5]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.adobe.flexide.nativelibs.Headlights.AdobePIPInitialize(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;IJLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V+0
j  com.adobe.flexbuilder.ui.UIPlugin$2.run()V+117
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run()V+11
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+29
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+5
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+91
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Lorg/eclipse/jface/window/Window$IExceptionHandler;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;)V+9
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI()I+555
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/Workbench;)I+1
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run()V+55
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+18
j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+99
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+149
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x02658c00 JavaThread "Code Model Worker" [_thread_blocked, id=2636, stack(0x3d200000,0x3d300000)]
  0x02658400 JavaThread "Code Model Worker" [_thread_blocked, id=1064, stack(0x3ce00000,0x3cf00000)]
  0x02657800 JavaThread "Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=5564, stack(0x3c360000,0x3c460000)]
  0x02657000 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4772, stack(0x3b6e0000,0x3b7e0000)]
  0x02656c00 JavaThread "Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=4224, stack(0x3b520000,0x3b620000)]
  0x02656400 JavaThread "Thread-4" [_thread_in_native, id=2792, stack(0x3b420000,0x3b520000)]
  0x02656000 JavaThread "Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=816, stack(0x3ac80000,0x3ad80000)]
  0x02655800 JavaThread "Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=6100, stack(0x08430000,0x08530000)]
  0x02655400 JavaThread "Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=4200, stack(0x08330000,0x08430000)]
  0x02654c00 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6092, stack(0x05b20000,0x05c20000)]
  0x06942000 JavaThread "Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=5904, stack(0x070f0000,0x071f0000)]
  0x069afc00 JavaThread "Provisioning Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=612, stack(0x06fb0000,0x070b0000)]
  0x053d7800 JavaThread "Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=5424, stack(0x05f30000,0x06030000)]
  0x0620b000 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5148, stack(0x06670000,0x06770000)]
  0x060f2800 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=2556, stack(0x06530000,0x06630000)]
  0x06061800 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5804, stack(0x06430000,0x06530000)]
  0x026cec00 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4876, stack(0x05e30000,0x05f30000)]
  0x05455c00 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2564, stack(0x05d30000,0x05e30000)]
  0x05454c00 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5088, stack(0x05980000,0x05a80000)]
  0x026ab000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3960, stack(0x05180000,0x05280000)]
  0x026a6c00 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5288, stack(0x05040000,0x05140000)]
  0x026a5400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5708, stack(0x04f00000,0x05000000)]
  0x026a4400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4168, stack(0x04dc0000,0x04ec0000)]
  0x0269a000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5960, stack(0x04c80000,0x04d80000)]
  0x02698c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5392, stack(0x04b40000,0x04c40000)]
=>0x02729000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=5152, stack(0x00090000,0x00190000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0265cc00 VMThread [stack: 0x04a00000,0x04b00000] [id=2992]
  0x026b7400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x052c0000,0x053c0000] [id=272]

VM state:synchronizing (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x02727548] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x0265cc00

Heap
 def new generation   total 78656K, used 39958K [0x08550000, 0x0daa0000, 0x12ff0000)
  eden space 69952K,  48% used [0x08550000, 0x0a637490, 0x0c9a0000)
  from space 8704K,  71% used [0x0c9a0000, 0x0cfbe488, 0x0d220000)
  to   space 8704K,   0% used [0x0d220000, 0x0d220000, 0x0daa0000)
 tenured generation   total 174784K, used 30117K [0x12ff0000, 0x1daa0000, 0x28550000)
   the space 174784K,  17% used [0x12ff0000, 0x14d59750, 0x14d59800, 0x1daa0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 65536K, used 48202K [0x28550000, 0x2c550000, 0x38550000)
   the space 65536K,  73% used [0x28550000, 0x2b462990, 0x2b462a00, 0x2c550000)
    ro space 10240K,  51% used [0x38550000, 0x38a7e978, 0x38a7ea00, 0x38f50000)
    rw space 12288K,  55% used [0x38f50000, 0x395ec970, 0x395eca00, 0x39b50000)

Code Cache  [0x02730000, 0x02b68000, 0x04730000)
 total_blobs=2158 nmethods=1952 adapters=140 free_code_cache=29150592 largest_free_block=256

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x0040d000     C:\My Softwares\Required\eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32\eclipse\eclipse.exe
0x772d0000 - 0x77450000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x75ca0000 - 0x75db0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x75450000 - 0x75496000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x75ba0000 - 0x75ca0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x75060000 - 0x750f0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x772a0000 - 0x772aa000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x76e30000 - 0x76ecd000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x75860000 - 0x7590c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x750f0000 - 0x75190000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x75430000 - 0x75449000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x74ee0000 - 0x74fd0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x74e30000 - 0x74e90000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x74e20000 - 0x74e2c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x73b20000 - 0x73ba4000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\COMCTL32.dll
0x75000000 - 0x75060000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x75360000 - 0x7542c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x72000000 - 0x7200d000     C:\My Softwares\Required\eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222\eclipse_1312.dll
0x748a0000 - 0x748a9000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x71080000 - 0x71100000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x75630000 - 0x7578c000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x75e70000 - 0x75ef3000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x754a0000 - 0x7552f000     C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6da9f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x71100000 - 0x71132000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x7c360000 - 0x7c3b6000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR71.dll
0x70570000 - 0x705bc000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d7a0000 - 0x6d7ac000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d320000 - 0x6d33f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x6d7e0000 - 0x6d7ef000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x74870000 - 0x74886000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x74830000 - 0x7486b000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x74770000 - 0x74787000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x74760000 - 0x7476b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x6d600000 - 0x6d613000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x74ea0000 - 0x74ed5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x74e90000 - 0x74e96000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x73820000 - 0x7385c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x73310000 - 0x73316000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x73b10000 - 0x73b20000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x73b00000 - 0x73b10000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x73ae0000 - 0x73af2000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x737d0000 - 0x73814000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x73ad0000 - 0x73ad8000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x73780000 - 0x73785000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x73e30000 - 0x73e4c000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x73e20000 - 0x73e27000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x73ac0000 - 0x73ac6000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x73790000 - 0x737c8000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x6d620000 - 0x6d629000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll
0x075b0000 - 0x07613000     C:\My Softwares\Required\eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\559\1\.cp\swt-win32-3659.dll
0x76c90000 - 0x76d0b000     C:\Windows\syswow64\comdlg32.dll
0x757e0000 - 0x75837000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
0x70810000 - 0x709ae000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x75f00000 - 0x76b4a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
0x75530000 - 0x75625000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WININET.dll
0x76b50000 - 0x76c87000     C:\Windows\syswow64\urlmon.dll
0x76d10000 - 0x76e2d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
0x75e60000 - 0x75e6c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll
0x75940000 - 0x75b3e000     C:\Windows\syswow64\iertutil.dll
0x705c0000 - 0x705d3000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x056c0000 - 0x056dd000     C:\My Softwares\Required\eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\559\1\.cp\swt-gdip-win32-3659.dll
0x70ab0000 - 0x70c40000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17514_none_72d18a4386696c80\gdiplus.dll
0x698c0000 - 0x699bb000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x6f980000 - 0x6fa75000     C:\Windows\system32\propsys.dll
0x68310000 - 0x6847f000     C:\Windows\system32\explorerframe.dll
0x685d0000 - 0x685ff000     C:\Windows\system32\DUser.dll
0x68250000 - 0x68302000     C:\Windows\system32\DUI70.dll
0x70600000 - 0x7063c000     C:\Windows\system32\oleacc.dll
0x74730000 - 0x7473e000     C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
0x73300000 - 0x73305000     C:\Windows\system32\msimg32.dll
0x720a0000 - 0x720ce000     C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
0x74d20000 - 0x74d2f000     C:\My Softwares\Required\eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\65\1\.cp\jWinHttp-1.0.0.dll
0x74050000 - 0x740a8000     C:\Windows\system32\WINHTTP.dll
0x73fb0000 - 0x73fff000     C:\Windows\system32\webio.dll
0x076a0000 - 0x076a7000     C:\My Softwares\Required\eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\296\1\.cp\jnicrypt.dll
0x74390000 - 0x7439d000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x74370000 - 0x74382000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x74360000 - 0x74368000     C:\Windows\system32\credssp.dll
0x75910000 - 0x75937000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
0x07a50000 - 0x07a91000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.nativelibs_4.5.1.313231\os\win32\x86\BridgeTalk.dll
0x5b210000 - 0x5b27a000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.nativelibs_4.5.1.313231\libs\adobe_caps.dll
0x75190000 - 0x7532d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
0x75840000 - 0x75852000     C:\Windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
0x73680000 - 0x736a1000     C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
0x75790000 - 0x757d5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WLDAP32.dll
0x3b620000 - 0x3b6d7000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.utils.osnative_4.5.1.313231\os\win32\x86\JNIToNativeBridge.dll
0x75e40000 - 0x75e45000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x68520000 - 0x68590000     C:\Windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
0x740c0000 - 0x740d9000     C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x736b0000 - 0x736bb000     C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
0x696d0000 - 0x696da000     C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
0x740e0000 - 0x740e9000     C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll
0x5c190000 - 0x5c199000     C:\Windows\system32\LINKINFO.dll
0x73390000 - 0x7339c000     C:\Windows\system32\mssprxy.dll
0x3c500000 - 0x3c50b000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.amt_4.5.1.313231\os\win32\x86\amt_win_jnilib.dll
0x72bd0000 - 0x72c5e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_50916076bcb9a742\MSVCP90.dll
0x743d0000 - 0x74473000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_50916076bcb9a742\MSVCR90.dll
0x5b120000 - 0x5b210000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.amt_4.5.1.313231\os\win32\x86\amtlib.dll
0x5b000000 - 0x5b115000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.amt_4.5.1.313231\os\win32\x86\amtservices.dll
0x5b760000 - 0x5b7ca000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.amt_4.5.1.313231\os\win32\x86\adobe_caps.dll
0x3c6b0000 - 0x3c6d8000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.amt_4.5.1.313231\os\win32\x86\asneu.dll
0x73540000 - 0x7354a000     C:\Windows\system32\wbem\wbemprox.dll
0x734e0000 - 0x7353c000     C:\Windows\system32\wbemcomn.dll
0x734d0000 - 0x734df000     C:\Windows\system32\wbem\wbemsvc.dll
0x73430000 - 0x734c6000     C:\Windows\system32\wbem\fastprox.dll
0x73410000 - 0x73428000     C:\Windows\system32\NTDSAPI.dll
0x5aae0000 - 0x5ab72000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.amt_4.5.1.313231\os\win32\x86\updaternotifications.dll
0x740f0000 - 0x74101000     C:\Windows\system32\NETAPI32.dll
0x740b0000 - 0x740bf000     C:\Windows\system32\wkscli.dll
0x5aba0000 - 0x5ac1d000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\taskschd.dll
0x3c5a0000 - 0x3c5ab000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.nativelibs_4.5.1.313231\os\win32\x86\Headlights.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=64m 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\SASHome\Secure;C:\Program Files\SASHome\x86\Secure;C:\My Softwares\Required\eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32\eclipse;
USERNAME=SINNPE
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 4089456k(1918596k free), swap 10221372k(7374968k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.2-b06) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_27-b07), built on Jul 19 2011 01:04:42 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Tue Sep 20 14:32:59 2011
elapsed time: 86 seconds




What is reason for this ??

Pleaeeeeeeesssssssssssseeee help to figure out the problem.
```

Comment: AFAIK flashbuilder is not compatible with these eclipse builds. I'm afraid you'll have to downgrade to Ganymede. Unless someone knows a better solution.

Comment: @RIAstar Helios should support Flash Builder 4.5. In fact it is the required version - 3.6.1. Indigo is not supported yet.

Comment: @VladimirTsvetkov you're right: Ganymede was the required version for FB4. I think you'll also be safer with the 32-bit version though.

Comment: But still i am not able to work with eclipse helios SR2  3.6 .... :(

Comment: Finally I reinstalled FB and cleaned registery .. and it is working now ...Total waste of time 1.5 day ...:(

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had a similar problem with Eclipse Indigo with CDT
I got the solution from here
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/664268/

add the following line to your **eclipse.ini** file

```
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
```